# Integral definition of curl

Tags: limits, vector-analysis, cross-product, curl

My book, Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering - K. F. Riley,

explains that the 'Integral definition of curl' is:-

$$\nabla\times a = \lim_{V\to0}(\frac{1}{V}\int_S dS\times a) $$

and then, after a few pages, it mentions:-

$$\int_S dS \times \nabla\phi = \int_C\phi dr$$

Now, if we take $a = \nabla\phi$ in the first equation, then $\int_S dS\times a$ becomes $0$ (because the curl of the gradient of anything is $0$). But this contradicts with the second equation.

So, what is the mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, in the first definition $S$ is a *closed* surface (i.e. a surface with no boundary), and $V$ is the volume enclosed by the surface.

In the second definition, $S$ is not necessarily a closed surface. $S$ may have a boundary, and the boundary of $S$ is the curve $C$.

But in the special case where $S$ *is* closed, then $C$ is an empty curve, so $\int_C \phi dr = 0$. There is therefore no contradiction.

Comment: Got it. I didn't know how to enter those closed integral signs on STACK EXCHANGE